# Weak limit points of an $L^1$-space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^1(\mu)$ with $$\int f_n\:{\rm d}\mu\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\gamma\tag1$$ for some $\gamma\in\mathbb R$.

> What does it mean if we say that $f\in L^1(\mu)$ is a limit point of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with respect to the $\sigma(L^1(\mu),L^\infty(\mu))$-topology (i.e. the weak topology on $L^1(\mu)$)? I clearly know the abstract definition for a general topological space, but is there an equivalent characterization available here which is easier to handle?
>
> And why can we conclude that $\int f\:{\rm d}\mu=\gamma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a subnet $f_{n_i}$ conveging to $f$ weakly. Hence $\int f_{n_i} g d\mu \to \int fg d\mu$ for all $g \in L^{\infty}$. Just take $g=1$ to con lude that $\int fd\mu=\gamma$.

Comment: Sub*net* means nothing else than sub*sequence* here, or am I missing something? Why does there exists such a subsequence? I mean, it's clear to me that this is true in metric spaces, but I'm uncertain how this property generalizes to more general topological spaces.

Comment: $L^{1}$ is not metrizable under weak topology. So a subsequence converging weakly to $f$ need not exist. We can only say a subnet of the sequenc $(f_n)$ exists.  @0xbadf00d

Comment: And the existence of a subnet is ensured in any topological space?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes any limit point of a net is the limit of some subnet.